# Is there a way to compile Air Mobile apps natively?

Tags: android, ios, flash, air

Is there any way to compile Adobe Air apps to native Android / iOS applications? I have no idea about iOS but in Android they need a huge(9MB~) download and i think it is a very big drawback for anything that can be sold?

I heard from an Adobe person at a conference that Angry Birds was made with Flash, if he wasn't lying, there must be a way.

Comment: For iOS, all AIR appliations that you create are cross compiled to objective C

Comment: then adobe is being an ass not cross compiling them with java for android, which is much more simpler

Comment: I did not state that they don't do it for android, I was unsure, hence left that out for someone else to fill in.

Comment: Regarding "I heard from an Adobe person at a conference that Angry Birds was made with Flash", that was probably about the upcoming Angry Birds version for the web, for Flash Player 11 in a browser (http://youtu.be/yOtnRSaoK-c). The native Angry Birds for iOS and Android was not made with Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex Builder 4.5+ can compile natively to iOS, but not to Android. In Android it runs on the AIR runtime, which needs to be installed (however, it is already installed on all recent phones).